# How to map URL in iron-ajax call to server with that of routes in server-side index.js?

Tags: ajax, node.js, polymer

```
<iron-ajax id="ajax_call_send_student_feedback" url="/student/feedback" handle-as="json" content-type='application/json' method="POST" body="{{student_feedback_body}}" on-response="ajax_response_student_feedback" on-error="ajax_error_student-feedback"></iron-ajax>
```

The above is my ajax-call to post body to server.As am running locally my url when this call is made is localhost:3000/student/feedback.
On the server-side , I have this following route to take care of the above ajax-call

```
app.post('/student/feedback',function(req, res) {


    var body = _.pick(req.body, 'student_loginID', 'student_feedback_subject', 'student_feedback_message');

    res.json(body);


});
```

But as soon as I make the ajax call , following error is shown on client-side.

```
POST http://localhost:3000/student/feedback 400 (Bad Request)
```

I have already checked the API end-point via Postman. So , there is some problem in the URL which I am not getting.
Ask for any other information , if I haven't provided.

Comment: Check your body. It might not be proper JSON. Also, try with hard coded data once

Answer (score 0):

this is probably a problem with your server route. inspect what's being sent to the server and how you're modifying that data.

1. log the value of `body` before your response returns json
2. send back a piece of hard-coded json

---

```
  app.post('/student/feedback',function(req, res) {
      var body = _.pick(req.body, 'student_loginID',  'student_feedback_subject', 'student_feedback_message');
      console.log(body)
      res.json({"foo": "bar"});
  });
```